# Include #N/A value in IF syntax VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, syntax

I have a problem including in my code the #N/A value in the cell. In my sheet, I want to eliminate the cell's content is the its value is either 0 or #N/A, but i don't know to write the VBA code for the #N/A.

This is the code that works for me, but it still gives an error when it encounters the #N/A cells.

```
For Each value In Sheets("Comments").Range("C2:Y600")
    If value = 0 Or value = "#N/A" Then
        value = " "
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing for the value test if the cell `IsNA`

```
Dim c As Range
Dim DefaultValue As String

DefaultValue = " "

For Each c In Sheets("Comments").Range("C2:Y600")
    If Application.IsNA(c) Then
        c.Value2 = DefaultValue
    Else
        If c.Value2 = 0 Then
            c.Value2 = DefaultValue
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I still get a type mismatch error when it encounters the N/A

Comment: Try using with a variable name other then `value` as this is a reserved keyword. Also, how have you declared your variable?

Comment: Dim c As Range like this?

Comment: yup. You could be running into issues by trying to declare/not declare `value`

Comment: Still getting the same error...

Comment: Which line is it erroring on? Have you got any other error values in your sheet?

Comment: @AncaVulc You cannot test both in one `if` because if it contains NA then testing for `c.Value2 = 0` fails. You need 2 `If` the first testing for `Application.IsNA(c)` and the second one testing for `c.Value2 = 0` but that is all explained in the link above your question (which is a duplicate of your question and was already solved).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Cheers - Think I need more morning coffee

Comment: One more question :D My sheet has about 300 lines and 20 columns to check and running it take a few minutes... Before that code, I'm simply running VLOOKUP s for each column, that's why it returns 0 or #N/A. Is there a way I can make it more efficient? The code for VLOOKUP is before the for.

Comment: @AncaVulc Actually this is a new question that has nothing to do with your original question and is better asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com if your code runs without showing errors.